# When does Prolog prompts 'yes' and when does it says 'true'

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel, gnu-prolog

I wrote the following knowledge base in Prolog:

```
likes(yamini,chocolate).
likes(anuj,apple).
likes(yamini,book).
likes(john,book).
likes(john,france).
```

Now, when I consult the above file and try the following commands:

```
| ?- likes(anuj,apple).      

(1 ms) yes
| ?- likes(yamini,chocolate).

true ? ;

no
```

I want to understand when does Prolog replies a 'yes' versus when does it replies 'true'.

Comment: Is this GNU Prolog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That output depends on the toplevel you are using. It seems you are using GProlog. It will output `yes` when the query succeeds and there are no choice points left (no other possible solutions).

And it will answer `true` when the query succeeds but there are still other possible solutions to be checked.

Comment: perhaps the implementers  thought `yes ?` would seem argumentative. :)

Comment: But `likes(yamini,chocolate).` has just one answer... I mean `chocolate` isn't a variable, then why would prolog think there could be other solutions...?

Comment: @yaminigoel: I believe GProlog is using first argument indexing so when proving the first clause it only "checks" whether there are any remaining clauses with first argument `yamini` which there exists (the third clause), therefore it leaves a choicepoint. If you query `likes(yamini, book)` instead it will answer `yes` because when it proves the third clause there are no remaining clauses with first argument `yamini`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an artefact of the toplevel (Prolog command line) implementation. Apparently you implementation says `true` when it could prove a goal and it is unsure whether there may be more solutions. If it is sure that there is only one solution, it says `yes`.

Here is what SWI-Prolog does:

```
?- likes(anuj,apple). 
true.
```

Prolog could successfully prove the goal `likes(anuj,apple)` and it is also sure there are no other ways to prove it otherwise one would see something like this:

```
?- member(X,[1,2]).
X = 1 ; 
X = 2.
```

where an `X` that makes the goal true has been found as `1` but there may be other solutions. And indeed there are, namely `2`.

Back to our example:

```
?- likes(yamini,chocolate).
true.
```

Comment: Incidentally, the "goal" should really have been called "conjecture" back in the 70s, shouldn't it? We want to make the conjecture a theorem...